# How to Select Eloquent based on foreign key in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I have this models:

```
class HrLeaveType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_leave_types';
    protected $fillable = [
              'id',
                  'company_id',
                  'leave_type_name',
              ];

    
    public function leavetypedetail()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Hr\HrLeaveTypeDetail');
    }

}

class HrLeaveTypeDetail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_leave_type_details';
    protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'leave_type_id',
                  'company_id',
                  'employee_type_id',
                  'leave_applicable_gender',
              ];

    public function leavetype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrLeaveType', 'leave_type_id', 'id');
    }  
    
    public function employeetype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployeeType', 'employee_type_id', 'id' );
    }        
    
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organization\OrgCompany','company_id');
    }
}
```

One HrLeaveType has many LeaveTypeDetail

I have this in my controller:

```
    $userCompany                    = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $employeeCode                   = Auth::user()->employee_code;
    $employeeemptypeid              = HrEmployee::where('employee_code', $employeeCode)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->pluck('employee_type_id')->first();
    $employeeegendercode            = HrEmployee::where('employee_code', $employeeCode)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->pluck('gender_code')->first();        
    if($employeeegendercode == 0) 
    {
        $leavetypes                     = HrLeaveType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get();
    }else{
        $leavetypes                     = HrLeaveType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get();
    }
```

gender_code (0=Female and 1=Male)
leave_applicable_gender (1=Both,2=Male and 3=Female)

One HrLeaveType has many LeaveTypeDetail. I want to generate a dropdown with HrLeaveType on condition.

if
$employeeegendercode == 0 then  $leavetypes   = HrLeaveType where $employeeemptypeid = employee_type_id in HrEmployeeType and leave_applicable_gender is 1 or 3

else

$leavetypes   = HrLeaveType where $employeeemptypeid = employee_type_id in HrEmployeeType and leave_applicable_gender is 1 or 2

At the moment, this is what I have in my view:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Leave Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <select id="leave_type" class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose Leave Type" tabindex="1" name="leave_type_id" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option value="">Select Leave Type</option>
                    @if($leavetypes->count() > 0)
                        @foreach($leavetypes as $leavetype)
                            <option value="{{$leavetype->id}}" {{ old('leave_type_id', $leaverequest->leave_type_id) == $leavetype->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$leavetype->leave_type_name}}
                            </option>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </select>
            </div>
```

But not kind of leave type to be seeing depends on gender

How do I complete  $leavetypes in

```
    if($employeeegendercode == 0) 
    {
        $leavetypes                     = HrLeaveType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get();
where leavetype->leavetypedetail->leave_applicable_gender == 1 or 3
    }else{
        $leavetypes                     = HrLeaveType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get();
where leavetype->leavetypedetail->leave_applicable_gender == 1 or 2
    }
```

to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `whereHas` eloquent with where condition. read this for more .. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

hope its help you